# Matrix Multiplication Using SSE Error __m128 to *float conversion?

Tags: c, matrix, sse

I'm trying to program matrix multiplication using SSE Intrinsic. I'm not sure if my code is correct and I can't compiler it either because I get an error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'float' to '__m128 *
```

Can someone double check my program so that my matrix multiplication is correct? Note also that this is for a square matrix.

Here is my code.

```
void Intrinsics (float * matrix_a, float * matrix_b, float * matrix_result, const int num_row, const int num_col) {
    __declspec(align(16)) float * a = matrix_a;
    __declspec(align(16)) float * b = matrix_b;
    __declspec(align(16)) float * c = matrix_result;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_row; ++i)
    {
       for(int j = 0; j < num_col; ++j)
        {
            __m128 *m3 = (__m128*)a[i];     // The error is here.
            __m128 *m4 = (__m128*)b[j];
            float* res;
            *(c + (j * num_col + i)) = 0;
          for(int k = 0; k < num_col; k += 4)
            {
                __m128 m5 = _mm_mul_ps(*m3,*m4);
                res = (float*)&m5;
                *(c + (j * num_col + i)) += res[0]+res[1]+res[2]+res[3];
                m3++;
                m4++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While code line the error is attributed to?

Comment: updated code with the error line

Answer (score 1):

I assume that it's `__m128 *m3 = (__m128*)a[i];` and the line after that that produce the error. You are trying to typecast a `float` to a **pointer** to __m128 which compiler is right to complain about.

I don't know the details of the intended algorithm. Assuming that the intent is to access four floats a[i]..a[i+3] as a single __m128, you need something like this:

```
__m128 *m3 = (__m128*)&a[i];
__m128 *m4 = (__m128*)&b[j];
```

or equivalent:

```
__m128 *m3 = (__m128*)(a + i);
__m128 *m4 = (__m128*)(b + j);
```

Comment: You should not access the __m128 fields directly. You can, however, see these types in the debugger. A variable of type __m128 maps to the XMM[0-7] registers.
Variables of type _m128 are automatically aligned on 16-byte boundaries.

Comment: We're dealing with a syntax error here -- attempt to assign a float to a pointer. What the user tries to do with the data he points to, is a different issue that may warrant its own question. :-)